# Apagar um registro após fazer uma consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Existe como após uma consulta apagar o resultado retornado de um banco?

Tenho uma tabela mensagem (de,para,mensagem) cada vez que consulto devo apagar a(s) mensagem(s) lidas.

Comment: Imagino que você procure um modo automático, porque usando os mesmos critérios do SELECT num DELETE você apagará a consulta recém feita...

Comment: O select pode garantir que os dados foram extraídos, não lidos , informação poderia ser perdida, uma solução poderia ser (depende da aplicação) , ler os dados mais recentes e um EVENT apaga os registros anteriores a um tempo X. Mas direto e numa única operacão não me ocorre.

Comment: Sim, só que o problema é que posso ter inserções durante a consulta. E quando eu for deletar * tem novos registros não lidos

Comment: Talvez se eu armazenasse os id dos objetos consultados e fizesse o delete depois.

Comment: Grave a data&hora da insersão e use esta data&hora para saber quais novos (select) e quais velhos (delete).

Comment: Seria mais fácil com um campo de `status` (lida ou não) para a mensagem. Imagino que tenhas esse campo, mas poste a estrutura da tabela para dar uma visão geral melhor sobre a questão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um `Stored Procedure` no seu banco de dados. Veja um exemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `database`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `consultaMensagem`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `consultaMensagem`(IN idMensagem INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM mensagem WHERE id = idMensagem;   
    DELETE FROM mensagem WHERE id = idMensagem;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sendo:

database -> seu banco de dados
consultaMensagem -> nome da sua procedure
idMensagem -> parâmetro de entrada para a consulta e exclusão

Entre `BEGIN` e `END` você desenvolve sua procedure, no caso esta executa uma consulta no banco de dados filtrando todos os registro que possuem o `id = idMensagem` (parâmetro passado à procedure). Em seguida, com o mesmo filtro, executa um `DELETE`, eliminando assim a mensagem consultada.

Para executar a `procedure`, faça desta maneira:

```
Call consultaMensagem(1);
```

Assim, a mensagem com `id = 1` será retornada e eliminada logo em seguida.

Comment: Na verdade como não sei se tem mensagem ou não, meu select é assim `SELECT * FROM MENSAGEM WHERE para=para`

Comment: Sem problemas @Thiago, basta alterar o `WHERE` do `SELECT` e do `DELETE`

Comment: criei conforme seu exemplo, mas ela esta deletando todas as mensagens em vez de deletar apenas do usuário passado pelo parâmetro: `CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE 'consultaMensagem'(IN idpara INT)
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE idpara = idpara;   
    DELETE FROM mensagens WHERE idpara = idpara;

END`

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui @Thiago e pelo que percebi quando o nome do campo e o parâmetro que ele recebe possui o mesmo nome, ele se perde e acaba exibindo e, consequentemente, removendo tudo. Tenta alterar o nome do seu parâmetro de entrada de `idpara` para `idReceptor`, por exemplo.

Comment: Funcionou! obrigado!